# SQL query to count data from specific day and time, grouped by classification

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table with this data:

```
PurchaseDate = <date & time>
Classification = <string>
Quantity = <integer>
```

I need to create report on how many Quantity per day, per Classification, with PurchaseDate between 14:00 and 17:00.

Anyone can help?

Using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired resiand your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

Testdata:

```sql
create table #class (
    PurchaseDate datetime
    , Classification varchar(30)
    , Quantity int
)

insert into #class (
    PurchaseDate
    , Classification
    , Quantity
)
select top 100 cast('20231124 15:00' as datetime) + (10 % row_number() over(order by @@spid))  + (1.0 / row_number() over(order by @@spid))
    , char(65 + row_number() over(order by @@spid) % 3)
    , ((100 + row_number() over(order by NEWID())) % 17)
from sys.objects so
```

The code:

```sql
select cast(purchasedate as date), classification, sum(quantity)
from #class
where cast(purchasedate as time) between '14:00' and '17:00'
group by cast(purchasedate as date), classification
```

It's a simple group by date. To get the times, I use the cast as time

Comment: That works. My problem was with getting the time and use it in the query. My first thought was using "having time ...". But, yours works. Thanks.

Comment: `hh:mm:ss` format is unambiguous I believe